# Communicating with all potential clients as a multi niche photographer

Tags: amateur, portfolio

This may be seen as a bit off topic, but I'm hoping it's a question that some photographers can associalte with and clear up for me.

I'm an amateur wanting to get more serious in the new year, and aiming to build up a portfolio of work that I will showcase on my own website, which will hopefully build up a client base.

I figured that a good way to get started would be to create a few 365 style projects that I can publish on my site and on social media. However, my interests vary a great deal, and therefore my photography will more than likely range from nature and local events, to more NSFW style topics.

My problem is, how to successfully communicate with people who will be interested in certain aspects of my work, without losing touch with those interested in others.

In theory, I'd like to set up a single social media presence, preferably Twitter, where I can freely post anything I want, and connect with anyone I want. Essentailly pointing people in the direction of whatever content they will be interested in. Problem is, social media sites like Twitter publicise ALL of your posts to ALL of your followers, so people who are following for nature/local photography will possibly unfollow me for my NSFW content. At the same time, some SFW followers may be potential clients in other areas, and vice versa.

So as a multi niche photographer, how can you engage with all potential clients, and showcase all portfolio peices ( in my case all 365 project shots ) via a single or limited number of social networks? How are you doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Social Media Dilema](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103243/a-social-media-dilema)

Comment: vtc b/c This is a Q about social media and communication, not photography.  Consider [interpersonal.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com) or [communitybuilding.SE](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I disagree w/ the vote to close. Questions about the business of photography are on topic (https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/614/questions-about-the-business-of-photography-on-or-off-topic) and this is about the business strategy of promoting one's photography business..

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/98609/should-a-photographer-use-a-pseudonym-when-doing-two-types-of-photography-that-m

Comment: I agree with @Hueco

Answer (score 5):

**Separate your audiences**. For example if you shoot product and boudoir, don't advertise them together, you could end up alienating both client base, as someone who's interested in someone to shoot their latest selection of doors.. they're not going to be interested in seeing racy boudoir shots. There can also be an impact on SFW filters. Social media algorithms will also reflect suggestions etc accordingly so you may shoot yourself in the foot.

As noted in a comment, this is also important: 'separate your branding as well. Using separate pages doesn't mean much if I labeled both Hueco's Photography and someone looking for family photos Googles me only to end of ogling some racy boudoir shots'. Also worth googling the name see if it's being used before you decide to use it.

That said. Nothing wrong with just having a blog/social media page, unrelated to commercial work and clients, and treat it as such, treat it as a project not an advertising tool.

I'd also highly recommend avoid the 'multi-niche' approach. It comes across very 'jack of all trades, master of none'. If you want to build up a portfolio and in turn a client base look at doing it one at a time and focus on a single specific genre.

Comment: But what if you're the jack of all trades, master of one? The only thing that I'd add is: separate your branding as well. Using separate pages doesn't mean much if I labeled both *Hueco's Photography* and someone looking for family photos Googles me only to end of ogling some racy boudoir shots.

Comment: Thanks, but as a complete amateur, at this point in tilme I really am a Jack of all Trades as I haven't yet established myself as a photographer in my prefered field, and probably won't for some time. I guess this is really more about connecting with clients rather than showcasing work. My question at https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/social-networking-as-a-multi-niche-freelancer/8018#8018 might clarify my problem better. Bear in mind that my website has multiple section/categories which are all completely non related to each other.

Comment: @WayneFA then sorry to say you won't successfully build a client base.  By attempting to appeal to everyone, you will end up appealing to no-one. Being successful in commerical photography isn't really a case of trying everything and find what fits.

Comment: If you check out my link @CrazyDino you'll see that this isn't just about photography.